# The logic of splice from coffeescript.org example

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Roaming through coffeescript.org faced this epicly simple, at first sight, example of compiling to js from coffee:
Coffee:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
numbers[3..6] = [-3, -4, -5, -6]
```

Js:

```
var numbers, _ref;
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
[].splice.apply(numbers, [3, 4].concat(_ref = [-3, -4, -5, -6])), _ref;
```

When hitting run button on the site with this example it returns that numbers variable,
but if looking onto the last JS line we get that _ref after comma, that if believing js docs has the least precedence but finally returns the right result and in here my visual logic breaks apart, whats the sense of writing such code? why do we ever need to cache that _ref inside concat and then after the parens return it after comma, just got my head exploding, why??? any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this line of code:

```
numbers[3..6] = [-3, -4, -5, -6]
```

What would you like it to return? All expressions in Javascript (and presumably in Coffeescript too) have a return value. The typical return value of `=` is the right hand side of the operator. So we need to return the array `[-3, -4, -5, -6]`. And we can't return just any old array: we need to return *that* array. (Remember that Javascript arrays are passed by reference.)

So when we look at this line of code:

```
[].splice.apply(numbers, [3, 4].concat(_ref = [-3, -4, -5, -6])), _ref;
```

First the left hand side of the comma is evaluated, doing the operation we want. However, this would return the return value of `splice`, which isn't what we want, since that would be the elements that were removed from the original array. So we need the comma operator.

The comma operator, as the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) describes:

> evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand

On the face of it, you'd think we could do this:

```
[].splice.apply(numbers, [3, 4].concat([-3, -4, -5, -6])), [-3, -4, -5, -6];
```

But that would be wrong. OK, here it would probably work. But we don't want to return an array that has those elements. No, we want to return the original array, the same array that we used in the `concat` call. So we need to cache the value (in `_ref`) and then refer to it again after the comma.